# Sum of frequencies of list of values in an other list

Tags: python, list

I have two lists and I want to calculate the sum of frequencies of one list of values in an other list.

```
a = [1,4,5]
```

I want to calculate the sum of frequencies of a in b in an efficient way:

```
b = [2,1,4,1,5,6,3,2]
```

The output should be 4 which is 2+1+1

Comment: `print(sum(b.count(i) for i in a))` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you need.

```
a = [1,4,5]
b = [2,1,4,1,5,6,3,2]

print(sum(b.count(i) for i in a))
```

**Output:**

```
4
```

Comment: This will be O(len(a) * len(b)) though, as count will have to iterate again on `b` for each value in `a`

Answer (score 3):

You can use the Counter from collections:

```
from collections import Counter

c = Counter(b)
sum(c[i] for i in a)
```

output:

> 4

Answer (score 2):

You can do it this way, iterating only once on each list:

```
from collections import Counter

a = [1,4,5]
b = [2,1,4,1,5,6,3,2]

counter = Counter(b)
res = sum(counter[value] for value in a)
print(res)
# 4
```

Counter will iterate only once on `b`, then we iterate once on `a` to sum the relevant counts, keeping the complexity at O(len(a) + len(b)).

The methods like `sum(b.count(val) for val in a)`, though, will be O(len(a) * len(b)), as `count` will have to iterate on `b` again for each item of `a`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`.count()`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html) method in a list comprehension:

```
sum([b.count(i) for i in a])
```

output :

> 4